# Why wrong this.propertyName reference inside abstract method realization?

Tags: typescript

Why in code below i got wrong this.name reference inside abstract method realisation?

```
abstract class Abstract {
  protected name: string;

  constructor () {
    this.abstractMethod();
  }

  protected abstract abstractMethod (): void;
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
  protected name: string = 'Concrete';

  protected abstractMethod () {
    console.log(this, this.name); // Concrete, undefined
  }
}

new Concrete();
```

[Link on example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Abstract%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.abstractMethod()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09protected%20abstract%20abstractMethod%20()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Concrete%20extends%20Abstract%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20'Concrete'%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09protected%20abstractMethod%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(this%2C%20this.name)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Concrete()%3B)

Comment: Are you sure? I don't get the error on link neither on my IDE.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to call virtual methods from a constructor in c#, java or javascript, as type invariants may break. (see Eric Lipperts post to see what's the problem with it, especially the comments section https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really know, what you want to achieve, but maybe this helps, sorry for my English

```
abstract class Abstract {
    protected name: string;

    constructor () {
        //this.abstractMethod();
    }

    protected abstract abstractMethod (): void;
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
    protected name: string = 'Concrete';

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.abstractMethod();
    }

    protected abstractMethod () {
        console.log(this, this.name);
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Concrete { name: 'Concrete' } 'Concrete'
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the compiled JavaScript can help in situations like this:

```
function Concrete() {
    _super.apply(this, arguments); // calls this.abstractMethod()
    this.name = 'Concrete';
}
```

The assignment doesn't take place until after the super call—the call to `Abstract`'s constructor—and so at the time `this.abstractMethod` is called `this.name` is `undefined`.

Comment: What a better way to fix that?

Comment: @КачаловТимофей there's multiple ways, but it's probably best not to be calling an abstract method in the abstract classes' constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon you observed is predictable, as the constructors run in the order from base classes to concrete classes. The best fix is to make the abstract classes constructor handle the name property:

```
abstract class Abstract {

  constructor (protected name: string) {
    this.abstractMethod();
  }

  protected abstract abstractMethod (): void;
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
  constructor() {
    super("Concrete");
  }
  protected abstractMethod () {
    console.log(this, this.name); // Concrete, undefined
  }
}

new Concrete();
```